# Icon not displaying properly on website

Tags: css, firefox, font-face

For some reason, two icons that show in IE and Chrome do not appear in Firefox and instead gives me some weird icon. I am using a font to display these.

[image]

I used firebug to track down exact CSS code for this but it simply shows

```
.icon-signin:before{
    content: "";
}
```

whereas in IE, it shows

[image]

and in Chrome it shows:

[image]

I honestly don't understand what's happening here.

In the actual CSS file it has the following line:

```
.icon-signin:before{content:"\e047";}
```

All I could gather from google search is that

```
:before
```

is outdated and that I should use

```
::before
```

Would this fix the solution?
But if that is the case, why is Chrome displaying the icon when it also reads the css code with :before, not ::before  ?

Comment: "Would this fix the solution?" Have you tried it?

Comment: I want to but since it's a company server, I cannot deploy without assurance..